# Spectral Centroid Calculation using librosa

Tags: python, signal-processing, librosa

I have found the following two ways of calculating the spectral centroid, but they do not return the same value.

Which is the correct version and how are the 2 different from each other?

1.

```
def spectral_centroid(x, samplerate=44100):
    magnitudes = np.abs(np.fft.rfft(x)) # magnitudes of positive frequencies
    length = len(x)
    freqs = np.abs(np.fft.fftfreq(length, 1.0/samplerate)[:length//2+1]) # positive frequencies
    return np.sum(magnitudes*freqs) / np.sum(magnitudes)
```

2.

```
cent = librosa.feature.spectral_centroid(y=y, sr=sr)
print(np.mean(cent.T, axis=0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Well both should be correct if you followed the right formulas. I would go with the [librosa](https://librosa.github.io/) implementation though, because I trust the development team behind it. Obviously, you can also use your approach if it provides an advantage in your use-case.

Now let's address **why are the results different?** This is due to the fact that your approach uses the [Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) implemented in [numpy.fft.rfft](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.rfft.html), where as the [librosa.feature.spectral_centroid](https://github.com/librosa/librosa/blob/f54cc970e6089b3d1254cdb430a8747e5e68a940/librosa/feature/spectral.py#L38) approach uses the [Short-Time Fourier Transform (STFT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-time_Fourier_transform). You can verfiy this by taking a look at the following librosa links: [spectral-centroid](https://github.com/librosa/librosa/blob/f54cc970e6089b3d1254cdb430a8747e5e68a940/librosa/feature/spectral.py#L38) & [spectrum](https://github.com/librosa/librosa/blob/f54cc970e6089b3d1254cdb430a8747e5e68a940/librosa/core/spectrum.py#L2300).

STFT and DFT give different advantages, so where as STFT is time dependent and the information of temporal change will not be lost, it is computationally more intensive and slower than DFT.

Comment: Thanks for your response. What I understood was that librosa will split the signal into shorter bins and calculate the centroid for each of those windows and present the result as an array. If that is correct, is taking the mean the best way of calculating the centroid over the entire time frame ?

Comment: I would say yes, the mean should be a good measure to determine the general spectral centroid, given equally long frames (which is the case).